# Java Server Thread Error using command line arguments on a mac terminal (Eclipse file)

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I'm trying to create a text messaging program in java which can behave as a client if the command line arguments doesn't include `"-l"` or a server if the command line arguments does include `"-l"`.

For this error, I am working on the server behavior.

The command line arguments for the server would be something like

```
java DirectMessengerServer -l 6004
```

Screenshot of error:
[image: Terminal error screenshot]

Code of DirectMessageServer.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DirectMessengerServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Thread Server = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                ServerSocket server_socket = null;
                Socket client_socket;
                String message1;
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    if (args[i] == "-l") {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                            client_socket = server_socket.accept();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                            String input_line = reader.readLine();
                            System.out.println("Received from client: ");
                            System.out.println(input_line);
                            output.println(input_line);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        //server.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Server.start();
    }
}
```

**My question** is how to solve the error and/or what does it actually mean when it says `thread - 0` exception and/or what does `"numberformatexception"` mean in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse `-l` to integer, that is the problem.

```
java DirectMessengerServer -l 6004
```

Your first argument is String type and the second is Integer.

This exactly what the screen shot error says.

`args[0]` for `-l`

`args[1]` for port number

I am not sure why you have a loop for your arguments but correcting the argument number would solved the problem in your question, that said you are not using port number variable and your code logic can be improved a bit.